# Why can't I set a referencing outlet for my NSTextView in XCode 4?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.2

I'm making a simple dialog in XCode 4 using the Interface Builder. I have three NSButtons, all of which are hooked up to their relevant IBOutlets. However I have an NSTextView, which I'd also like to hook up. I have the declaration for it in `MyDialog.h`:

```
@interface MyDialog : NibLoaderOC {
@public
  IBOutlet NSTextView* tv;
  IBOutlet NSButton* acceptButton;
  IBOutlet NSButton* editButton;
  IBOutlet NSButton* rejectButton;
}
@end
```

But when I drag the 'New Referencing Outlet' line over `tv`, it won't highlight. If I try and make a new outlet, it says:

> **Could not insert new outlet connection:** Could not find any information for the class named MyDialog

I have tried restarting XCode, this does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me restarting Xcode solved the problem. Just in case anyone else hits this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd still be interested in a proper solution, I fixed this by just manually editing the xib code to create the link.

This has the unfortunate side-effect of Interface Editor refusing to play nicely with the file (although all my manual edits were correct, and the code compiles and runs perfectly).

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that .m file was moved inside en.lproj folder.

Just delete (reference only) the .m file from the Xcode and moved .m out of the en.lproj. 
Add it again.It will fix the issue.

Don't worry, you will get all your connections back.

Answer (score 1):

i got this bug in xcode 4.6.0. restarting xcode didn't fix it for me. deleting the derived data for the project, then restarting xcode did fix it.

delete /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check for is to make sure that if you have a custom class that you specify it under "Custom class" in the Identity inspector of Interface Builder.

So for instance if you have the following declaration

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
@public
  IBOutlet MyCustomView* aCustomView;

}
@end
```

Make sure you add that into the inspector as pictured. Otherwise I've found that you won't be able to hook it up.

[image: Inspector view]

Comment: Thanks! that was it for me... I copied/paste from another UIViewController so the custom class was not correct.